# Browsing history

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

It would be nice (in my opinion) for the site to keep track of questions I browsed.  Similar to how Reddit keeps track of recently read.  I think this would help because many times I close a tab only to later think I should have upvoted that question.  The work around is to go through my browser history which is pretty cluttered.  Browser history only works if i'm on the same pc etc as well.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/add-a-recently-viewed-tab-in-the-user-account-page , and I haven't found a good duplicate on this site yet.

Comment: I wish I could upvote it :(

Comment: "*Browser history only works if [I'm] on the same pc*" - well, that depends on the browser, my history in Chrome persists across all instances of that browser that I'm signed into. But yes: it would be a welcome feature.

Comment: Sidenote : Ctrl+Shift+T to reopen the last closed tab, at least on Firefox.

Comment: On Chrome, at least, if I start typing part of the question title from memory in the address bar, it searches the history and suggests URLs from it. I use this extensively to find questions that I visited recently. Ctrl+Shift+T also reopens recently closed tabs on Chrome, by the way. Another good tool is a decent session manager plugin for your favorite browser; then you can save sets of interesting questions in a session.

Comment: It exists on app. I don't know why not on desktop.