# How is the "(Browsing) History" tab implemented in the app?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-app

With the [SO app coming out today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android), I was reminded of the one feature I actually appreciated in the SE app, **browsing history**.

Here is the feature in the SE app (left) and the shiny new SO app (right). Freehand circles added by me for your enjoyment.

[image: History tab in SE app] [image]

I'm curious to know how this is implemented, and if it could be added to the main site as well.

I know a main site browsing history feature has [been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/add-a-recently-viewed-tab-in-the-user-account-page/116315) [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/add-a-recently-viewed-tab-in-the-user-account-page/116315) [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276773/browsing-history), but could the same method that's being currently used in the apps also be used on the main site?

Comment: Because your browser already has a browsing history? All that is doing is storing the information locally on your device so you can view it later, which is the same thing your browser does for you as its History feature. We don't store it in the *database* and probably never will.

Comment: @animuson ah I wasn't sure how that was implemented. That makes sense for why it isn't on the main site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "recently viewed questions" feature in the apps is implemented completely client-side and is meant to serve the same function as history in a browser (since we aren't a browser and that history was just going into a black hole).  Really, I made it because I need to check the same question over and over when fixing bugs and I can't just hit refresh to these the same page.

Since this is being done on device, on a data store that has very low usage, we have a lot less to worry about than the web team.

Comment: Thanks for stepping in and providing this answer =) I think it's non-obvious that it's implemented this way, so hopefully others think so too and will find this useful.